# SQL Server : how to avoid duplicate data?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

[image]

I want to query above picture.

Left picture is original data, right picture is query data.

```
select distinct ID, Nickname, Revision 
from test_table
```

This query do not show above picture.

How to avoid duplicate data?

Comment: what is the result you are getting currently?

Comment: i want to get only last revision data. and i use sql server.

Comment: @JaydipJ -- BobT is the 3rd version for user ID 1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If SQL Server, using window function `ROW_NUMBER` in subquery:

```
select t.id, t.nickname, t.revision
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over (
            partition by t.id order by t.revision desc
            ) rn
    from your_table t
    ) t
where rn = 1;
```

Or using `TOP with ties` with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
select top 1 with ties *
from your_table
order by row_number() over (
        partition by id order by revision desc
        )
```

If MySQL:

```
select t.*
from your_table t
inner join (
    select id, MAX(revision) revision
    from your_table
    group by id
    ) t1 on t.id = t1.id
    and t.revision = t1.revision;
```

Answer (score 5):

Another trick using `TOP 1 with TIES`

```
SELECT Top 1 with ties *
    FROM your_table t
Order by row_number() over (partition BY t.id order by t.revision DESC)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct ID, Nickname, MAX(Revision) 
from test_table 
group by ID
```

Comment: you don't have to use both distinct and group by clause in a same statement